# Unable to do subtraction in Jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a build pipeline. I am still learning groovy. I am doing something simple like this

```
stage('test'){
def temp = 3 \\ reading this value from other env variable 
while(temp != 1) {
temp=temp-1
echo temp
}

}
```

It always echoes 3 and while is never-ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the value from the environment variable, you're getting it as a String

You need to convert it to an Integer

```
def temp = env.SOMETHING.toInteger()
```

Or, define it as an integer instead of using `def`:

```
int temp = env.SOMETHING
```

Comment: Thank you. Works flawlessly.